# How to add class only to the header of group of links

Tags: angular, router, routerlinkactive

I have a list like to:

```
<ul>
<li><a class="group-active">Group 1</a>
    <ul>
        <li routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="['/group1/page1']">Group 1 - Page 1</a>
        <li routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="['/group1/page2']">Group 1 - Page 2</a>
        <li routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="['/group1/page3']">Group 1 - Page 3</a>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a>Group 2</a>
    <ul>
        <li routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="['/group2/page1']">Group 2 - Page 1</a>
        <li routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="['/group2/page2']">Group 2 - Page 2</a>
        <li routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="['/group2/page3']">Group 2 - Page 3</a>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a>Group 3</a>
    <ul>
        <li routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="['/group3/page1']">Group 3 - Page 1</a>
        <li routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="['/group3/page2']">Group 3 - Page 2</a>
        <li routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="['/group3/page3']">Group 3 - Page 3</a>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I need:
change the class "group-active" (of the first group) when i choose one of their elements. Their elements works fine, but i can't apply the style to corresponding element header.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That's a good question. I could see many people needing this.

Export the routerLinkActive to a template variable and then use `isActive`:

```
<li><a [class.group-active]="r1.isActive || r2.isActive || r2.isActive">Group 1</a>
    <ul>
        <li routerLinkActive="active" #r1="routerLinkActive"><a [routerLink]="['/group1/page1']" #r1="routerLinkActive">Group 1 - Page 1</a>
        <li routerLinkActive="active" #r2="routerLinkActive"><a [routerLink]="['/group1/page2']">Group 1 - Page 2</a>
        <li routerLinkActive="active" #r3="routerLinkActive"><a [routerLink]="['/group1/page3']">Group 1 - Page 3</a>
    </ul>
</li>
```

You could also write a simple directive that has a `boolean` like this:

```
@Directive({
   selector: '[any-active]',
   exportAs 'anyActive'
})
public class AnyActiveDirective implements DoCheck {
  @ViewChildren(RouterLinkActive)
  public links: QueryList<RouterLinkActive>;

  public active: boolean = false;

  public constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  public ngDoCheck() {
     if(this.links) {
        const active = !!this.links.find((link)=>link.isActive);
        if(this.active !== active) {
            thia.active = active;
            this.cdr.markForCheck();
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Then in the template:

```
<li any-active #group1="actActive"><a [class.group-active]="group1.active">Group 1</a>
    <ul>
        <li routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="['/group1/page1']" #r1="routerLinkActive">Group 1 - Page 1</a>
        <li routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="['/group1/page2']">Group 1 - Page 2</a>
        <li routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="['/group1/page3']">Group 1 - Page 3</a>
    </ul>
</li>
```

You can try the first approach if your template is kind of static, but if your links are generated with a `*ngFor` then give the custom directive a try.

**UPDATED:**

I don't think my previous answer was very good. The `routerLinkActive` directive will set the CSS value if **any** children with `routerLink` are active.

Therefore, this should be enough to get it working:

```
<li><a routerLinkActive="group-active">Group 1</a>
    <ul>
        <li routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="['/group1/page1']">Group 1 - Page 1</a>
        <li routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="['/group1/page2']">Group 1 - Page 2</a>
        <li routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="['/group1/page3']">Group 1 - Page 3</a>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think your code i can using it in another similar case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44976194/angular-2-4-ngstyle-apply-different-style-depeding-its-father-element-active

Answer (score 1):

Well, 
I found my solution and i share it with you. Angular is very smart. Just I need to add the same routerLinkActive in the corresponding element:

```
<li><a routerLinkActive="group-active">Group 1</a>
...
<li><a routerLinkActive="group-active">Group 2</a>
...
<li><a routerLinkActive="group-active">Group 3</a>
...
```

I hope it helps someone else.

Comment: Nice! It watches all inner routerLinks. I didn't think of checking for that.