# Angular 2/4, "ngStyle". Apply different style depeding its father element active o inactive

Tags: angular, ng-style

I need to apply a style to an element when it parent element is actived. I'm using routerLinkActive to apply CSS Class and works fine, but deppending if the father element is actite apply one inline style (display: block), in other cases apply another (display: none).

If parent element is active:

```
<li class="active">
   <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: block;">
</li>
<li>
   <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
</li>
```

When I choose another element:

```
<li>
   <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
</li>
<li class="active">
   <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: block;">
</li>
```

I have an extended list of items with their respectives Links. Each "sub-menu" has its own list of elements.

Comment: Is your menu inside an `*ngFor` or is it a static one? How do you apply your `"active"` class to your `li` tags?

Comment: Is a static one. I apply the active class using "routerLinkActive"

Comment: Oh I see, then @Alex answer would be better for you

Comment: Sorry but, i don't find the answer from @Alex. Where is it?

Comment: Seems like is username changed to @shevaroller

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with CSS only:

```
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

.active .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

Check out this [live demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/U2dEv71q5OSaGQSFTRQn) to see how it works.

Comment: Thanks, but i need to use ngStyle.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this the angular way, I'd suggest making an object or array out of your menu so you can make dynamic changes to it in real time using data binding.

To make a dynamic menu with Angular, simply create a representation of your menu in your component. You can either provide it with static values if you do not plan on loading your menu from a database or making more complex modification to it. Otherwise, you can create a class for your menu and even your sub-menu to take the full advantage of object oriented programming.

Component:

```
menus: any [] = {
    { subMenus: any [] = { {}, {} }, active: boolean = true; },
    { subMenus: any [] = { {}, {} }, active: boolean = false; }
}
```

Once you have your menu set up in your component, you can then make it fully dynamic by using angular data binding brackets in your html and using *ngFor to avoid repeating html.

Html:

```
<li *ngFor="let menu of menus" [className]="menu.active?'active':''">
   <ul *ngFor="let subMenu of menus.subMenus class="sub-menu" [style.display]="menu.active?'block':'none'">
</li>
```

You can use [ngStyle] to give more than one style at a time.

You can add

```
(click)="menu.active=!menu.active"
```

to your 'li' tag to make it active or inactive on a click or

```
(click)="SetActive(menu)"
```

create a function in your component that will set every menu beside the clicked menu to inactive.

Comment: I need to do using ngStyle directive :(

Comment: Simply need to write `[ngStyle]="menu.active?'{display:block}':'{display:none}'"`. Can also write the style in your component or use [className] and make CSS class for both active and inactive submenu

Answer (score 0):

If you use a boolean flag template variable:

```
<li [class.active]="flag">
   <ul class="sub-menu" [style.display]="flag ? 'block' : 'none'">
</li>
<li>
   <ul class="sub-menu" [style.display]="flag ? 'none' : 'block'">
</li>
```

You can also use the router active directive to control the flag:

```
<li [class.active]="link.isActive" #link="routerLinkActive">
```

And use `link.isActive` instead of `flag` elsewhere.